# Change wordpress dashboard menu order and titles

Tags: wordpress

I'm using alamak theme ( https://themeforest.net/item/alamak-responsive-one-page-portfolio-theme/6502151 ) and I want to change dashboard menu order for posts ( Portfolio - About Us - Team - etc) and rename them. I cannot find anywhere to do so, and cannot find the register_post_type function on theme's files so I cant tweak them :/

Do you guys have any clue how to do so ?
Thanks.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/changing-admin-menu-labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want to use a plugin or not, but here you go!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks :)